# Huge join query leads to max row size error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm executing a SQL query that joins 100+ tables together and I am running into the following error message:

> Cannot create a row of size 8131 which is greater than the allowable
>   maximum row size of 8060.

Just would like to know what my options are at this point? Is this query impossible to execute? Are there any workarounds?

Appreciate any help

Thanks

Comment: Just as a side note, if you need to join over 100 tables you probably have design issues much more important than getting this query to run.

Comment: What is your select clause?

Comment: @JNK not sure that should be relegated to "side note."

Comment: don't have an option with respect to the tables (I'm importing the data from spreadsheets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not the join, or the number of tables.  It is the number and size of the fields in the SELECT.  You are reaching a row size limit, not a row count limit.

Make sure you are not using any "*" in your SELECT, then eliminate any unused fields and trim/limit strings where possible.

Comment: thanks for your feedback.  sadly, i'm already specifying which columns to pull.  i'll see what i can with respect to trim/limit.

Comment: Is there any way you can share the list of fields in your select, along with their associated size/type info?

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/233a9853-4e63-4bc2-a948-785bd73f16a0/cannot-create-a-row-of-size-xxxx-which-is-greater-than-the-allowable-maximum-row-size-of-8060?forum=sqltools):

You're hitting SQL's row size limit which is 8060 bytes (eg an 8K page). Using normal data types you cannot have a row which uses more than 8060 bytes, and while you can use a `varchar` to allow the smaller bits of data to offset the larger ones, with 468 columns of data you're looking at an average column width of 17.2 bytes.

If you convert `varchar(x)` to `varchar(max)` issue will be resolved.

Please also refer: [How SQL server stores of the size of the row is greater than 8060 bytes Difference Between varchar(max) and varchar(8000)](http://saurabhsinhainblogs.blogspot.in/2014/01/cannot-create-row-of-size-xxxx-which-is.html)

Comment: varchar(max) is a good solution, but also can create some optimization headaches down the road.  I'd suggest the op find another way around it if possible.  In many cases varchars are just defined arbitrarily large, beyond what is needed.

Comment: I never had problems with optimization because of this varchar(max) but maybe you're right. I have to investigate it. Thanks